# Show Gui Menu with Double Tapping

Tags: autohotkey

i have this code for context menu ( its working perfectly )

Details

- when i hit V => it will send V
- when i double tap V => it will show up context menu commands

```
;-------- Layout

Menu, ps_context, Add, Normal, blending_normal_command
Menu, ps_context, Add,
Menu, ps_context, Add, Cancel, close_context


;-------- Hotkey

; Double Tap V = Context Menu 
; Single Tap = Send V

$v::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
Menu, ps_context, Show
else
Send v
return


;------- Command

blending_normal_command: 
Send, {shift down}{alt down}{n down}
Send, {shift up}{alt up}{n up}
return

close_context:
return
```

Result : [Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNFip.gif)

i have no problem with context menu. but when it comes to gui menu and apply same code above it just doesnt work.here's the code for gui i posted 2 code for comparison ( GUI menu & context menu ).is there a workaround to make the below code to make it work? currently double tapping V doesnt do anything but single tapping works

```
;-------- Hotkey

; Double Tap V = Gui Menu
; Single Tap = Send V

$v::
If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show
else
Send v
return


;-------- Layout

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, XposA, YposA
XposA-=+0
YposA-=+0

Gui, blend_custom_layer: Font, s9,Segoe UI
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Color, EEAA99

Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x0 y0 w20 h20 BackgroundTrans gclosewanrmenu, ✘
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x21 y0 w200 h20  BackgroundTrans gnormal_blend_layer_command, Normal

Gui blend_custom_layer:+LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
Gui blend_custom_layer:-Caption
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show, x%XposA% y%YposA% h500 w500, menus
return



;------- Command

normal_blend_layer_command:
    Gui, blend_custom_layer:Submit
        send {alt down}{shift down}{n down}
        send {alt up}{shift up}{n up}
        Sleep, 50
        Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show 
    Return

closewanrmenu:
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Destroy
return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Why do some lines in my script never execute?](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/FAQ.htm#autoexec)**

> **Any lines you want to execute immediately when the script starts**
> **should appear at the top of the script, prior to the first hotkey,**
> **hotstring, or Return.**
> **For details, see [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).**

If you want that code to be executed after you press the hotkey, put it in a labeled subroutine and call it from your hotkey subroutine.

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

;-------- Layout

CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
; MouseGetPos, XposA, YposA
; XposA-=+0
; YposA-=+0

Gui, blend_custom_layer: Font, s9,Segoe UI
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Color, EEAA99

Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x0 y0 w20 h20 BackgroundTrans gclosewanrmenu, ✘
Gui, blend_custom_layer:Add, Button, x21 y0 w200 h20  BackgroundTrans gnormal_blend_layer_command, Normal

Gui blend_custom_layer:+LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
Gui blend_custom_layer:-Caption
; Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show, x%XposA% y%YposA% h500 w500, menus

        RETURN   ; === end of auto-execute section ===


;------- Command

normal_blend_layer_command:
    Gui, blend_custom_layer:Submit
    send {alt down}{shift down}{n down}
    send {alt up}{shift up}{n up}
    Sleep, 50
    Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show 
Return

closewanrmenu:
    ; If you destroy the gui you won't be able to rebuild it by double tapping V 
    Gui, blend_custom_layer:hide
return

;-------- Hotkey

; Double Tap V = Context Menu 
; Single Tap = Send V

$v::
    If (A_PriorHotKey = A_ThisHotKey and A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
    {
        MouseGetPos, mX, mY
        Gui, blend_custom_layer:Show, x%mX% y%mY%
    }
    else
        Send v
return
```

Comment: you are a life saver thank you. its working now. but another question how do i make the popup appear in mouse position when i execute double tap V

Comment: if you dont mind answering my another question. why does everytime i run or open the ahk the GUI pops up on my mouse screen even i ddnt execute hotkey , is there a way to make it hide on first run. thank you so much i really appreciate taking time helping me ( nvm : i figure it out i added  Gui, blend_custom_layer:hide to line 21 once again thank you so much for helping me

Comment: I commented out the lines that show the gui on first run.